# C: How to free the initial section of an allocated string?

Tags: c, string, malloc, free

How can I free a string up to a certain point? For example if I have:

```
char *s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 21);
s[20] = '\0';
int i = 0;
while (i < 21)
{
    s[i] = i + 'a';
    i++;
}
```

And then I cut off the string at some point and store that half:

```
*(s + 10) = '\0';
char *m = s + 11;
```

Is there a way to free `s` up to `s + 10` or the first `\0`?

Comment: No. You can free the end with realloc. What do you mean by free anyway?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but note that you [shouldn't cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3425536).

Comment: In `while (s[i] != '\0')` you are making an assumption of what the allocated memory contains. Anything up to the byte you specifically set with `s[20] = '\0';` could be `0`. You have *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Yeah... I was writing a random example... Just changed it..

Comment: @tuple_cat: in the same area, `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `s` has been allocated by the system, you can perform a `realloc` on it to shorten the size:

```
s = realloc(s, 11);
```

But you cannot free the start of an allocated zone without freeing the rest, that you cannot. Use `memmove` & `realloc` to shift the data and reduce size afterwards.

Attempting to `free` a pointer which hasn't been allocated, or an allocated pointer plus an offset results in undefined behaviour.

You could do (as you suggested yourself, but with problems fixed :)):

```
char *c = strdup(s + 10);
free(s);
s = c;
```

so now `s` points to the end of the string.

alternative without `strdup` but using standard functions only (with the risk of forgetting the null-termination char):

```
char *c = malloc(strlen(s) - 10 + 1);
strcpy(c,s + 10);
free(s);
s = c;
```

and the `memmove` solution I was hinting about at first (avoids to allocate/free but offset/size is trickier to compute):

```
int offset = 10;
int size = strlen(s) - offset;
memmove(s,s+offset,size);
s[size]='\0';  // null-terminate
s = realloc(s,size+1);  // adjust size after null-termination
```

Comment: Is something like this going to work?
`char *c = strdup(s + 10);
 free(&s);
 s = strdup(c);
 free(&c);`

Comment: probably but drop the `&` in `free`. I'll edit my answer to include your code, it solves it (and since you accepted it :))

Comment: @CosminSerdean `char *c = strdup(s + 10); free(s); s = c;` is all you need.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that's telepathy, I figured out that much in my edit.

Comment: Note that `strdup()` is not defined by the standard.

Comment: @pmg you're right, but that's pretty common. 3 upvotes means that I'm morally compelled to edit for an alternative :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Indeed.  Your edit appeared right when I entered my comment.

Comment: yes, I usually credit people if I lift some of their code :) maybe the `memmove` approach is more performant because you don't have to allocate & free, just realloc.

Comment: @pmg *Note that `strdup()` is not defined by the standard.*  Which standard?  [`strdup()` has been part of of the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) since probably 2001 or so, judging from the [dates for POSIX issue 6 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

Comment: @AndrewHenle: the [ISO/IEC 9899 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to free `s` up to `s + 10` or the first `\0`?

No. Not in the standard library at least.

There's `realloc` but it isn't guaranteed to "free `s` up to `s + 10` or the first `\0`".